# Spring microservices timeout docker swarm

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-cloud

I have spring-cloud app with 3 services:
eureka-server + gateway(zuul) + user-service (2 instances)

In localhost everthing is working and i can acces:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users
```

and get simple string response.

but when i deyploy app in docker swarm i get exception when accesing this endpoint.

Here is stacktrace from gateway:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:118) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:410) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:159) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.255.0.142:37599 [/10.255.0.142] failed: connect timed out
at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
... 125 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.255.0.142:37599 [/10.255.0.142] failed: connect timed out
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:81) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
... 127 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
... 169 common frames omitted
```

we can see there, he is trying to access:

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.255.0.142:37599 [/10.255.0.142] failed: connect timed out
```

Docker created 4 containers and all 3 servies are registred in eureka-server:

[Eureka registred gateway and 2 instances of user-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jpiz.png)

```
EDGE-SERVER n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 10.255.0.140:edge- server:8080
USER-SERVICE    n/a (2) (2) UP (2) - user-service:fb96da56c12016400991bc8d1fd67931 , user-service:4a8d845517c42c7265247c6b19cf551f
```

ip of user-service instances:

```
http://10.255.0.142:37599/
http://10.255.0.143:36603/
```

Properties:

1. gateway

application.yml

```
zuul:
  routes:
    user-servie:
      path: /api/users/**
      serviceId: user-service

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://server:8761/eureka/
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: edge-server

server.port: 8080
```

2. eureka-server

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
```

3. user-service

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: user-service

server:
  port: ${PORT:0}

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://server:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 6
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 2
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    image: spring-cloud_server:latest
    networks:
      - webnet
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"

  edge-server:
    container_name: edge-server
    build: ./edge-server
    image: spring-cloud_edge-server:latest
    networks:
      - webnet
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - server

  user-service:
    container_name: user-service
    build: ./user-service
    image: spring-cloud_user-service:latest
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - server
    deploy:
      replicas: 2

networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: Can you ping `10.255.0.142`?

Comment: From localhost i cant ping this container.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the swarm, not localhost.

Comment: I know its been a while, however have you discovered what caused the problem?  I'm having the exact same problem using Greenwich release train & docker swarm.  docker-compose works fine though

Answer (score 2):

So after a lot of pain I thought I would share how I fixed this issue.

The issue appears to be related to the ingress network.  By setting the endpoint mode to be dnssr the network has individual ip addresses.

> endpoint_mode: vip - Docker assigns the service a virtual IP (VIP) that acts as the front end for clients to reach the service on a network. Docker routes requests between the client and available worker nodes for the service, without client knowledge of how many nodes are participating in the service or their IP addresses or ports. (This is the default.)
>
> endpoint_mode: dnsrr - DNS round-robin (DNSRR) service discovery does not use a single virtual IP. Docker sets up DNS entries for the service such that a DNS query for the service name returns a list of IP addresses, and the client connects directly to one of these. DNS round-robin is useful in cases where you want to use your own load balancer, or for Hybrid Windows and Linux applications.

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

This example would have the following docker-compose:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    image: spring-cloud_server:latest
    networks:
      - webnet
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"

  edge-server:
    container_name: edge-server
    build: ./edge-server
    image: spring-cloud_edge-server:latest
    networks:
      - webnet
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - server

  user-service:
    container_name: user-service
    build: ./user-service
    image: spring-cloud_user-service:latest
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - server
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr

networks:
  webnet:
```

Another thing to note:  You cannot expose the ports and define the endpoint_mode as dnsrr.  The error message will be.

> EndpointSpec: port published with ingress mode can't be used with dnsrr mode